# How to change radius of circles but keep pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found some code online to draw circles around a center circle. How do I change the radius of the smaller circles without affecting the layout (currently all the circles shift and are not centered around the large circle anymore).

This happens when I change the radius(width & height) in the css file. Changing the large circle radius also causes the whole group of circles to shift right or left (although they maintain their symmetry).

Here is my code:

```js
var div = 360 / 6;
var radius = 150;
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(parentdiv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes parent is square
var offsetToChildCenter = 20;
var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
  childdiv.className = 'div2';
  childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
}
```

```css
#parentdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 150px;
  margin: 150px;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentdiv"></div>
```

I would also like to move the circles to the center of the screen but I am not sure how.

I am very new to html/css/js and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the border-radius in the css not efficient ? for the centering : `html{display:flex;height:100%;}body{margin:auto}` would do for your snippet.

Comment: @G-Cyr The border-radius is used for making the circles, I meant width/height my bad! but the centering worked thanks!

Comment: okay, about the position , there is two vars to update :  `radius` and `offsetToChildCenter` , i just updated my demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate my comment. border-radius is a CSS rule to round boxe's corners.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius
>
> The border-radius CSS property rounds the corners of an element's outer border edge. You can set a single radius to make circular corners, or two radii to make elliptical corners.

to modify the size , you can do it from the css file too, about the position , there is two vars to update :  `radius` and `offsetToChildCenter`

Demo

```js
var div = 360 / 6;
var radius = 180;
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(parentdiv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes parent is square
var offsetToChildCenter = 40;
var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
  childdiv.className = 'div2';
  childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
}
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}

#parentdiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 150px;
  margin: 150px;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Yes sorry I editted my comment too late. I meant I was changing the width/height to change the radius of my circles!

Answer (score 1):

You can center the circles by applying Flexbox to the parent circle's parent element. In my case, the parent element is `<body>`.

```css
/* Apply Flexbox and use justify-content to 
   center parent circle horizontally. */
body {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

To adjust the diameter of the smaller circles, you would have to remove the `width` and `height` properties in your `.div2` selector and let Javascript calculate and set the width and height.

```js
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');
var div = 360 / 6;
var radius = 150;

var offsetToChildCenter = 50; // Change me!

var offsetToParentCenter = parseInt(parentdiv.offsetWidth / 2); //assumes parent is square
var totalOffset = offsetToParentCenter - offsetToChildCenter;

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; ++i) {
  var childdiv = document.createElement('div');
  childdiv.className = 'div2';
  childdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  
  var y = Math.sin((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  var x = Math.cos((div * i) * (Math.PI / 180)) * radius;
  
  childdiv.style.top = (y + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  childdiv.style.left = (x + totalOffset).toString() + "px";
  
  // Let your JS code calculate the width and height
  childdiv.style.width = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  childdiv.style.height = `${offsetToChildCenter * 2}px`
  
  parentdiv.appendChild(childdiv);
}
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#parentdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 150px;
    
    /* Use 50% to ensure the element will always be a circle. */
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    /* Remove width and height from CSS */
    /* width: 40px; */
    /* height: 40px; */
    background-color: red;
    
    /* Use 50% to ensure the element will always be a circle. */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentdiv"></div>
```